# Blazor client doesn't reach API endpoint in the same solution

Tags: .net, api, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor client project which I want to use an API in the same solution. But I can't seem to reach the API. In the blazor project `program.cs` I have set the BaseAdress like this

```
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

Inside the blazor app I have an Authservice which is trying to call the API. The service's register method looks like this.

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register(UserRegisterViewModel model)
        {
            var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Account/Register", model);
            return result;
        }
```

As you can see the Register-method is trying to call a register-action in a account controller, which I have in an API in the same solution. This is the Action:

```
    [Route("Account")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AccountController(IConfiguration configuration, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAsync([FromBody]UserRegisterViewModel model)
         {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                UserName = model.Email
            };

            IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return BadRequest(result.Errors);

            return Ok();
        }

        .....
        .....
}
```

But for some reason I never reach to action `RegisterAsync`. Why is this? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: It looks kind of Ok. So what do the Dev Tools (F12) show in the network tab? Is there a 404 or a 50x code?

Comment: It makes a request to https://localhost:44327/Account/Register and get a 404 in response. And that is expected since 44327 is the port of the client and not the port of the API

Comment: OK, then you will have to configure something to replace `builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress`

Comment: Hmm, okay. Can I do that and still avoid hard-coding the port?

Comment: What does debug tools (F12) / network is saying ?

Comment: As I mentioned above. It makes a request to localhost:44327/Account/Register and get a 404 in response. And that is expected since 44327 is the port of the client and not the port of the API